# Add values to a list where data is missing

Tags: c#, list, linq

I am creating a table of counts of the number of times a user has used a particular filter.

In order to do this I am adding log entries to a list which currently only contains values which have been logged.

the code I am using to do this is shown below:

```
public List<ViewItFilterUseCountModel> KeyIndicatorUseCount()
    {
        var ndtms2Utils = new NDTMS2UtilsEntities();

        var valueQuery = (from keyIndicators in ndtms2Utils.spr_KeyIndicator_Views_Count()
                          select keyIndicators);

        List<ViewItFilterUseCountModel> keyIndicatorUseCountList = new List<ViewItFilterUseCountModel>();

        foreach (var value in valueQuery)
        {
            ViewItFilterUseCountModel model = new ViewItFilterUseCountModel();
            model.LogDate = value.LogDate;
            model.MonthYear = value.MonthYear;
            model.Name = value.KeyIndicator;
            model.Count = value.KeyIndicatorCount;

            keyIndicatorUseCountList.Add(model);
        }

        return keyIndicatorUseCountList;
    }
```

I need to check for each combination of the MonthYear and Name variables whether data is present if there are no entries for this combination I need to create a row in the list with the Count variable set to null.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the code bellow inside the `KeyIndicatorUseCount` method, after filling the `keyIndicatorUseCountList` list with the data from DB. The code inserts the missing entries.

```
var allNames = keyIndicatorUseCountList
    .Select(i => i.Name).Distinct().ToList();

var allMonthYears = keyIndicatorUseCountList
    .Select(i => i.MonthYear).Distinct().ToList();

var allNamesMonthYears = allNames
    .SelectMany(n => allMonthYears, (n, m) => (Name: n, MonthYear: m));

var missingEntries = allNamesMonthYears.
    Except(keyIndicatorUseCountList.Select(i => (i.Name, i.MonthYear)));

foreach (var entry in missingEntries)
{
    ViewItFilterUseCountModel model = new ViewItFilterUseCountModel();
    model.MonthYear = entry.MonthYear;
    model.Name = entry.Name;
    model.Count = 0;
    keyIndicatorUseCountList.Add(model);
}
```